# React TypeScript - Merge two arrays into one and display as list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a react typescript project. I have two strings that are comma separated, which I'm turning into an array. One of the array contains the file's name the other the file's link path. I want to combine the first item in my first array with the first item in my second array and so forth. Like this:

```
array1 = ["Invoice","Privacy Policy","Terms of Condition"]
array2 = ["link/here.com", "another/download/link.com", "lastlink.com" ];

//Merged link to look like this mergedArray[]:
0: {name: "Invoice", link: "link/here.com"}
1: {name: "Privacy Policy", link: "another/download/link.com"}
2: {name: "Terms of Condition", link: "lastlink.com"}
```

I need to then wait until `Formlist` is rendered and then if the `array1` is not empty to loop through and spit out as an `li`

The two things I need help on are merging the two arrays and then displaying. here is my current code:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {

    if(this.state.FormList.length && this.state.FormList[0].fileLocationsString) {

        let array1 = this.state.UserList[0].fileLocationsString.split(',');
        let array2 = this.state.UserList[0].fileNameString.split(',');
        let mergedArray = //Here is where we combine arrays ??

        this.setState({ FileDownloadList: mergedArray });

        <ul>
            {this.state.FileDownloadList.map((item,i) => 
                <li key={i} href={item.link} target="_blank">item.name</li>
            )}
        </ul>               
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {need to call it here}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: What does 900301 relate to?

Comment: @HMR thank you I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce to form the object you need

```js
ar1 = ["Invoice","Privacy Policy","Terms of Condition"]
ar2 = ["link/here.com", "another/download/link.com", "lastlink.com" ];
output= ar1.reduce((acc,curr,i)=>{
  acc[i]={...acc[i],name:curr,link:ar2[i]}
  return acc
 },[])
 console.log(output)
```

and then iterate using `map`

```js
view = ( <ul > { output.map((o, i) => <li key = {o.name } href={o.link} target = "_blank" > item.name < /li>)} </ul>);}

return ( <div > {
        view
  } </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So using your above code I was successfully able to merge both arrays into one. The problem I'm having is with the `and then iterate using map` where am i placing this code?

Comment: remove  `this.setState({ FileDownloadList: mergedArray });` and the rest of the code underneath and replace it with this code it construct a view which is a list and you iterate through the array using map to construct your list

Comment: Thank you now I get an error with href.  For some reason I get an error on the `href` it says `type: any is not assignable to type DetailedHTMLProps`

Comment: I made a mistake. Needed to add the href to the A tag

Answer (score 1):

You could use spread operator or concat:

```
mergedArray = [...array1, ...array2];
```

or

```
mergedArray = array1.concat(array2)
```

You shouldn't call setState on render method, because you'll cause an infinite loop.

```
getFileDownloadList(): any[] {
    if(this.state.FormList.length && this.state.FormList[0].fileLocationsString) {

        let array1 = this.state.UserList[0].fileLocationsString.split(',');
        let array2 = this.state.UserList[0].fileNameString.split(',');
        return [...array1, ...array2];        
    }

    return [];

}

public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    return (
        <div>
           <ul>
            {this.getFileDownloadList().map((item,i) => 
                <li key={i} href={item.link} target="_blank">item.name</li>
            )}
           </ul>    
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To merge the arrays, you can simply loop over one of them, and create a new entry on the merged array. This assumes both arrays are the same size.

```js
let mergedArray = [];
for( let i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i ) {
    mergedArray.push({
        name: array1[i],
        link: array2[i]
    });

    // You can also do this if you don't like push
    // mergedArray[i] = {
    //     name: array1[i],
    //     link: array2[i]
    // };
}
```

Now that merged array has all the data you need, you need to render it. You were actually really close. First, we default the view to null. Null won't be rendered. If the content exists, we replace the view with our `<ul>`.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {

    let view = null;
    if(this.state.FormList.length && this.state.FormList[0].fileLocationsString) {

        let array1 = this.state.UserList[0].fileLocationsString.split(',');
        let array2 = this.state.UserList[0].fileNameString.split(',');
        for( let i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i ) {
            mergedArray.push({
                name: array1[i],
                link: array2[i]
            });
        }

        // I'd remove this. Causes re-render for no reason (and an infinite render loop)
        // this.setState({ FileDownloadList: mergedArray });

        view = (
            <ul>
                {mergedArray.map((item,i) => 
                    <li key={item.name} href={item.link} target="_blank">item.name</li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );         
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {view}
        </div>
    )

}
```

I noticed you are putting the merged array in-state but this isn't really necessary. It causes a re-render even though you already have the data you need to display it. I recommend one of the following:

1. Don't put it in state. Just let the render method generate it each time.
2. Put it in state, but do so when the data is put in state (not in the render method)

It is also recommended that you use unique, reproducible keys for React array elements. This really only causes issues with animations.

Comment: Awesome this helped. For some reason I get an error on the `href` it says `type: any is not assignable to type DetailedHTMLProps`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other responses, if you are sure that `array1` and `array2` are always same length, then the best and clean way I think is:

```
array1.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => [...acc, { name: curr, link: array2[index] }], [])
```